# Does going to a graduate school with less prestige than your undergraduate school hurt you?

Tags: graduate-school, computer-science, undergraduate, salary

I am trying to decided whether pursing a Master's in Computer Science will make me more competitive for a job designing video games. I went to a prestigious undergraduate school and finished strongly. The graduate schools which offer Master's programs with concentrations in video game design are less prestigious than my undergraduate school.

The average starting salary with a graduate degree from one of them is actually $30k less than my starting salary with just an undergraduate degree.

If I attend a less prestigious graduate school, will that cancel out my undergraduate degree? Could I end up making less money with my graduate degree from one of these less prestigious schools? Will employers make the false assumption that I attended a lesser graduate school because I did poorly as an undergraduate?

Comment: Please clarify -- is your long term goal to work in academia, or in industry?

Comment: If you are doing a PhD to go into academia you should ignore all statistics about money because professors don't make much in comparison to similar industry positions.

Comment: @Corvus industry

Comment: Is the average starting salary for the graduate school you mention for your field, or across many fields?

Comment: @mac389 a variation of my field

Comment: As a word of warning from one software developer to another, game design seems to have a very high turnover/fail rate. Daybreak Games last month, for example. If you get a more generalized CS degree, your job security will be higher. You can also go to more prestigious Master's programs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Edited heavily based on further information provided by OP*

**If you are going into industry, or pursuing a Master's, it may hurt you in the short term**

A Master's degree is mostly course work. It's too short for you to create a body of work that stands on its own. The quality of the courses largely determines, consequently, the quality of the Master's. Prospective employers may use an institution's reputation as a heuristic/proxy for the quality teaching.

Attending a less prestigious institution will make it more difficult to get interviews. Not being able to attend the bigger names also means you miss out on their alumni networks.

**Create a compensatory professional network that overcomes these limitations.** Most Master's in CS programs have a semester-long project. Make an impressive project and shop it around. This is a good way to build rapport with potential employers.

Comment: Awesome answer.  Computer science is the undergraduate and some form of video games/interactive media is the graduate.  Any feedback on that? :-)

Comment: PhD or Master's?

Comment: Master's Degree

Comment: Eep!  You are making me strongly reconsider my plans of going to grad school. Thank you for the excellent and informative answer!

Comment: M.Sc vs no M.Sc. is a different question from M.Sc. at one place vs another.

Comment: Understood. The more prestigious schools just don't have as good as a video game program though, so I never really considered them

Comment: @Evorlor To add my two cents.  If you went to a good undergrad school and majored in CS, my impression is that it is usually a mistake to then go get a masters in (some form of) CS.

Comment: @LevReyzin I have the opposite impression living near the California bay area. More education is not always commensurately valued, but it is often enough to pay off.

Comment: @Evorlor In contrast to my above comment, the field of game development is very different from CS generally. The only positions I can imagine studios would reward you for pursuing a graduate degree would be AI and business administration. Game developers generally are not like enterprise software development firms, the pay is lower and the work is longer.

Comment: @Tim Pay is lower, work is longer, but you forgot to mention...the difficulty is greater as well. Job security is non-existent. The average career of a game developer is 4-10 years before they switch industries. etc. The career choice isn't being debated...just the path to it. :-)

Comment: _A Master's degree is mostly course work_ — There are two types of Msater's degrees in CS and related fields.  **Professional/terminal** master's degrees are _entirely_ coursework. **Research** master's degrees require a certain amount of research culminating in a thesis; the balance of coursework versus research varies significantly from one program to the next.

Comment: @JeffE good point, I'll look further into MS for this field. I thought they were classes + one semester long project.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience people care more about whether you have the appropriate skills for the job at hand rather than where you went to college.

What work-related experience do you have in your field?

Do you have a professional network you can leverage to get the attention of people you might not otherwise?